# Pandas for duplicating one line to fill DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck at a dead end and I'm using some code that's decidedly un-Pandas for what should be a very simple task in Pandas. I'm sure there's a better way.

I have a DataFrame that I will extract a single line from and create a new DataFrame like so:

```
>>> sampledata
float_col  int_col str_col  r    v  new_coltest      eddd
0        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
1        0.2        2       b  5  NaN          0.2 -1.394550
2        0.2        6    None  5  NaN          0.2  0.290157
3       10.1        8       c  5  NaN         10.1 -1.799373
4        NaN       -1       a  5  NaN          NaN  0.694682
>>> newsampledata = sampledata[(sampledata.new_coltest == 0.1) & (sampledata.float_col == 0.1)]
>>> newsampledata
float_col  int_col str_col  r    v  new_coltest      eddd
0        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
```

What I would like to do is to copy that single line in "newsampledata" n times, where n is a known integer. Ideally the final DataFrame with the n lines overwrites the one-line "newsampledata" but this is not critical in any way.

I'm currently using a for loop to execute `pd.concat` n-1 times in order to get the DataFrame populated, but this is not fast due to the way that `concat` works. I have also tried the same type of tactic using `append` instead, and this is slightly slower than `concat`.

I have seen a few other questions asked about similar items, but many have not seen this exact question before. Also, I have been steered away from map/apply due to performance concerns, but if you have seen good performance in this method please let me know and I'll try that as well.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
N = 10
df =pd.DataFrame(newsampledata.values.tolist(),index=np.arange(N),columns=sampledata.columns)
print (df)
   float_col  int_col str_col  r    v  new_coltest      eddd
0        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
1        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
2        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
3        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
4        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
5        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
6        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
7        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
8        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783
9        0.1        1       a  5  1.0          0.1 -0.539783

print (df.dtypes)
float_col      float64
int_col          int64
str_col         object
r                int64
v              float64
new_coltest    float64
eddd           float64
dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

Is small `DataFrame` is faster `sample` and `reindex` methods, in large `DataFrame` constructor method.

```
N = 1000
In [88]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(newsampledata.values.tolist(), index=np.arange(N), columns=sampledata.columns))
1000 loops, best of 3: 745 µs per loop

In [89]: %timeit (newsampledata.sample(N, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True))
The slowest run took 4.88 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 470 µs per loop

In [90]: %timeit (newsampledata.reindex(newsampledata.index.repeat(N)).reset_index(drop=True))
1000 loops, best of 3: 476 µs per loop
```

---

```
N = 10000
In [92]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(newsampledata.values.tolist(), index=np.arange(N), columns=sampledata.columns))
1000 loops, best of 3: 946 µs per loop

In [93]: %timeit (newsampledata.sample(N, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True))
1000 loops, best of 3: 775 µs per loop

In [94]: %timeit (newsampledata.reindex(newsampledata.index.repeat(N)).reset_index(drop=True))
1000 loops, best of 3: 827 µs per loop
```

---

```
N = 100000
In [97]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(newsampledata.values.tolist(), index=np.arange(N), columns=sampledata.columns))
The slowest run took 12.98 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 6.93 ms per loop

In [98]: %timeit (newsampledata.sample(N, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.07 ms per loop

In [99]: %timeit (newsampledata.reindex(newsampledata.index.repeat(N)).reset_index(drop=True))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.87 ms per loop
```

---

```
N = 10000000
In [83]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(newsampledata.values.tolist(), index=np.arange(N), columns=sampledata.columns))
1 loop, best of 3: 589 ms per loop

In [84]: %timeit (newsampledata.sample(N, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True))
1 loop, best of 3: 757 ms per loop

In [85]: %timeit (newsampledata.reindex(newsampledata.index.repeat(N)).reset_index(drop=True))
1 loop, best of 3: 731 ms per loop
```

Comment: Good solution, seems to work without issue and I agree, it is faster. Didn't know how to set up the index, will have to remember this one!

Comment: On a previous version you had a numpy version, with the drawback, that dtypes where transformed to object. How does this solution compare in performance when casting back to the original datatypes? Maybe numpy is still faster ;)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 - I try it.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 - I try it and it is very slow `In [108]: %timeit numpy_tile(newsampledata,10000000)`
`1 loop, best of 3: 7.42 s per loop`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Wondering how pandas implements this. Maybe, I'm checking the source later the day

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you could just `sample` it with replacement

```
newsampledata.sample(n, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

or with `reindex`

```
newsampledata.reindex(newsampledata.index.repeat(n)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use concat without using a for loop explicitly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[.1]})
repetitions = 4
res = pd.concat([df]*repetitions)
print(res)
```

Output

```
   a    b
0  1  0.1
0  1  0.1
0  1  0.1
0  1  0.1
```

So on my sample frame, this is indeed faster than using for loops by a factor of roughly 5. However, I'd expect different solutions not using concat to be significantly faster.

To show ho slow concat is, some benchmark in  comparison to one of jezrael's solutions
[image]

Comment: concat is very slow. A one line dataframe took 1.5s for n=10,000

Comment: you are right. However, this solution is at least faster than using a for loop directly.

Comment: performed some benchmarks against jezraels solution, to show how slow concat is

Answer (score 1):

one of a bajillion ways to do this

```
pd.concat([df.query('new_coltest == 0.1 & float_col == 0.1')] * 4)
```

[image]